# Is it possible to select the polygon with the maximum area with a query in GeoDjango or PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, geodjango

I have lots of urban area multipolygons and I need to select the one with the largest area. At the moment I iterate through each object and calculate the area for each but this is inefficient. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you can call ST_Area directly in GeoDjango, in conjunction with an aggregate query, but you could use a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/). For example, using the correct Postgres query, as posted by @MikeT,

```
top_area = ModelName.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM sometable ORDER BY ST_Area(geom) DESC LIMIT 1')[0]
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this exact solution. Blazing fast. I had up to now been wary of the 'raw' feature because several sources warn bad things might happen if you start using it.

Comment: Yes, if you are using an ORM, it is discouraged to use raw, but if you are using it for analytical purposes rather than saving state, it is probably ok. I couldn't figure out how to do it directly in GeoDjango, though, hence the raw suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

With SQL, this query is:

```
SELECT *, ST_Area(geom) FROM mytable ORDER BY ST_Area(geom) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This calculates area for each geometry for the whole table.

If you use `ST_Area(geom)` frequently, you can make an index on the expression:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_geom_area_idx ON mytable (ST_Area(geom))
```